# my Facebook precise location has me at a location hours after I left

Tags: facebook-messenger

I sent my precise location to a friend on Facebook so they can meet up with me while I was out on the town. They got the first location and then I went someplace else.. they called me 2 hours later and said they were at the first place and that it said showed below my name the time I last updated, now today they said it says "yesterday at 9:30pm"  I have been on FB a few times since then and my GPS is on and I am home

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes . I saw this difference when i'm on 3G and when i'm on Wi-Fi.

Sometimes when i'm on 3G my location is in other city. I think is based on cell network .

Before my current network i didn't had issues like this . But you can check wich adress you have sent.

It's the same situation ?

Comment: thank you for your reply.. its through Facebook.. you send someone your precise location through nearby friends .. even though I moved the map shows me still in the same place since last night.. usually its fairly accurate